# How is the new way to call PresentationButton since Xcode beta 2?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement PresentationButton like documentation says but is not working.

This is for Xcode beta 2

```swift
PresentationButton(destination: LoginScreen(),
    label: Text("Login"))
```

I´m getting this error "Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to expected argument type '() -> _'"

Comment: The second argument should be a closure - check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentationbutton/3326830-init?changes=latest_minor).

Answer (score 3):

should be this:

```swift
PresentationButton(destination: LoginScreen(),
    label: { Text("Login") })
```

or this:

```swift
PresentationButton(destination: LoginScreen()) { Text("Login") }
```

instead.